# Django - add model field validator in __init__

Tags: django, django-admin, django-models

I need to add a field validator through an abstract class.

The code I'm working with supposes that every class inheriting from this abstract class has a field `name`, but this field itself isn't defined in the abstract class unfortunately.

So I tried the following, but I'm not sure what is the good way of finding the field in `self._meta.fields`, since this is a list..??

```
class AbsClass(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        abstract = True
    def __init__(self, *args, **kw):
        super(AbsClass, self).__init__(*args, **kw)
        name_field = [f for f in self._meta.fields if f.name == 'name'][0]  # Is there another way?
        name_field.validators.append(my_validator)
```

Comment: Why would you not add the field to the abstract base class if every subclass needs that field?

Comment: @IainShelvington I have then to rework the codebase.

Comment: You can access the field by calling `self.name` or `getattr(self, 'name')` since `name` is an attribute of the class.

If I was you I would seriously reconsider "reworking" the codebase to add the name field to the `AbsBase` class

Comment: @IainShelvington `self.name` is giving access to the value of the field, not the `db.models.fields....` instance

Comment: You really need to add the name field to `AbsBase` with the custom validator in the field definition. If you don't want to refactor your code then you may as well add the validator to every definition of the name field and not have an abstract base class at all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need [`Options.get_field`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.6/django/db/models/options.py#L347):

```
...
name_field = self._meta.get_field('name')
name_field.validators.append(my_validator)
...
```

Your approach, however, doesn't seem like a good idea: you model's field instances are shared between all instances of your model (their references are stored in a class attribute, not in instance attributes). This means that every time you instantiate an object of your model, you'll be adding *another* copy of `my_validator` to the field's validators, because you're adding it to the same field instance.

You could implement a metaclass for your abstract base class and add the validator at compile time instead of tampering with field instances at runtime, something along the lines of this (not tested):

```
from django.utils.six import with_metaclass
from django.db.models.base import ModelBase

# inherit from Django's model metaclass
class AbsClassMeta(ModelBase):

    def __new__(cls, name, bases, attrs):
        if 'name' in attrs:
            attrs['name'].validators.append(my_validator)
        elif name != 'AbsClass':
            # is it an error to not have a "name" field in your subclasses?
            # handle situation appropriately
        return super(AbsClassMeta, cls).__new__(cls, name, bases, attrs)

class AbsClass(with_metaclass(AbsClassMeta, models.Model)):
    ...
```

Note that your `AbsClass` class itself will also be created using this metaclass. If you decide to throw an exception in `AbsClassMeta.__new__` if the class doesn't have a `name` field, you need to take this into account, since your `AbsClass` class doesn't have a `name` field.

Comment: Thanks that's exactly what I was looking for. Helpful to understand django models `__init__` limitations as well

Answer (score 1):

In Django 2.x

instead of

```
name_field = self._meta.get_field('name')
name_field.validators.append(my_validator)
```

you can do:

```
name_field = self.fields['name']
name_field.validators.append(my_validator)
```